# Dockerfile: run commands in volume

Tags: linux, docker, containers, dockerfile, volume

I am building an image based on an existing image from the docker hub. In this official image, there is a volume declared (the data directory of a database).

I want to add files to this directory (to initialize a database).

However, after every command, the content of this directory seems to be disappeared.

How can I apply changes or create files in this volume directory?

Comment: Yes, the volume is initialised, see for example http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/

Comment: RUN commands cannot modify the contents of a predefined VOLUME at build time, the changes are discarded with each new layer. You could try using an entrypoint script that runs when the container starts and adding the files at that point.

Comment: @jww why should this question be off-topic? There are almost 70,000 Docker-related questions on Stackoverflow and of course it is about programming/development since is use docker to run my database and application...

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the VOLUME declared in the image with the host.
In this way whatever you will write to the volume will be stored on host.
you can mount your volume in this way

```
docker run -v /foo:/bar example/example command
```

Comment: in this case, this does not help me, because I want to initialize the data in the container (which is a volume) at build time

Comment: I would suggest initializing the database using the entrypoint script. In this way your image size won't be larger as well.